# Lambda Invocation from Another Lambda Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function from another lambda function in Kotlin in the following way :

```
val lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build()

      
val functionName = "backend-test-InternalLambda"
println("Calling function : $functionName")
val result = lambdaClient.invoke(InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(functionName).withPayload(payload).withInvocationType(InvocationType.Event))
println("Result = ${Gson().toJson(result)}")
```

When I check my cloudwatch logs of the lambda function,

```
2022-09-28T02:53:40.817+05:30   Calling function : backend-test-InternalLambda

2022-09-28T02:53:58.239+05:30   END RequestId: b8a772f2-c191-425f-afc4-6e173fef2181

2022-09-28T02:53:58.239+05:30   REPORT RequestId: b8a772f2-c191-425f-afc4-6e173fef2181 Duration: 20026.33 ms Billed Duration: 20000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 207 MB

2022-09-28T02:53:58.239+05:30   2022-09-27T21:23:58.239Z b8a772f2-c191-425f-afc4-6e173fef2181 Task timed out after 20.03 seconds
```

As you can see, the statement where I print the result does not get executed.
Moreover, when I check the logs of the invoked lambda, there is no sign that the lambda was actually invoked.

I thought this could be a permission issue but my `.yml` file contains the following iam role :

```
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Resource:
        - '*'
```

Interestingly, when I do this whole thing on my local using `sls offline` where my local lambda function calls `backend-test-InternalLambda`, that works perfectly fine.

What could be going on here?

Comment: Looks like the invoked function did not complete or return a result within the 20 second configured timeout of the invoking Lambda function. It's not a permissions issue. Double check logs for the invoked function or view its invocation count metrics.

Comment: Hey! I thought that could be the case and that's why called the lambda asynchronously by mentioning invocation type as event. Also double checked that the lambda has not been invoked.

Comment: Most likely your lambda is running within a VPC without proper internet access and can therefore not reach the other lambda. Therefore it just times out trying to reach it.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for your answer! Any idea how do I verify this and possibly resolve this?

Comment: Check the configuration of your lambda. Is it in a VPC or not? That is just part of the lambda config...

Comment: I think @luk2302 is probably correct here. See [Troubleshoot networking issues in Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-networking.html) for how to either provide internet access to the Lambda function or how to provide AWS Lambda service connectivity to the Lambda function via a VPC endpoint.

Comment: Yes! The lambda from which I was invoking was in a vpc while the invoked lambda was not in the vpc and hence the invoking lambda was just timing out without throwing any error as such.